# 2 ideal inductors in parallel

Tags: circuit-analysis

Would 2 ideal inductors in parallel carry currents according to current division even if the excitation is DC?

I am asking this because my spice simulation is showing they will carry equal currents, despite having unequal inductances.

A possible explanation what I have thought is, since the inductors become short for DC, so they carry same current. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Which spice are you using?  I know LTspice adds a mOhm of resistance to every inductor.

Comment: Same resistance to every inductor ???? I mean irrespective of their inductances ????

Comment: Yes. Though my wording was bad, it doesn't "add a mOhm", but if no series resistance is set for the inductor, it defaults to a mOhm.

Answer (score 3):

Inductors with zero resistance would split the current according to the reciprocal of the inductances. In other words a 1nH inductor in parallel with a 1uH inductor (0.999nH) and 1A of DC flowing would split 0.999A:0.001A.

SPICE does not handle this possible real-world situation well, but we can certainly confirm it using superconducting circuitry and SQUIDs.

Comment: The impedence of both inductors is zero at dc, does this come about from the limit behavior?  Do you have a source for the experimental demonstration of this?

Comment: @AndrewSpott Consider applying a voltage across the two inductors in parallel. The current in each will increase linearly but with a 1000:1 ratio. Short the input to cause a persistent current to flow and the ratio is preserved. Source- personal experience. There's probably a mathematical proof for this, somewhere.

Comment: Thanks.  I was thinking of the steady state, but forgot that you have to *get* to the steady state somehow.

Comment: for ideal inductors: $$ I={\int{V}dt \over L} $$ that division by the inductance will cause the ratio in paralleled inductors.

Comment: Can I say that a dc current of 6 A would distribute between 12 H and 6 H inductances as 2 A and 4 A respectively ????

Comment: Yes, that's right. It's just the same equation as a resistor current divider (but with inductances).

Comment: @DebajyotiDatta Please keep in mind that real-world inductances **do** have ohmic resistance!

Comment: Yes they do, i know sir, i was talking about superconducting stage