# Multisim results not matching handwritten results

Tags: circuit-analysis, transformer, inductor, multisim

I was given a project with the following question:
[image: Picture of problem]

I calculated the current going through inductor 2 in transformer 2 as 4 phase angle -30.

\$Vs = 1440 V RMS\$

\$V_1 = \frac{1}{3} * V_S = 480 V RMS\$

\$V_2 = \frac{1}{2} * V_1 = 240 V RMS\$

\$I_{Z2} = \frac{240 V RMS}{30 \angle{30}} = 8V RMS\angle{-30} \$

\$I_2 = \frac{1}{2} * 8V \angle{30} = 4V RMS\angle{-30}\$

However, in AC Analysis, Multisim returns \$ 2 \angle{-30} \$.
[image: Multisim Results]
The AC magnitude is 1440 V. Between points 1-0, it reported 1.44k V, 3-4 it reported 480V, 5-0, it reported 240V. The current flowing into Z1 is 7.99999 A with -29.99977 phase angle. T1 and T2 have 3:1 and 2:1 turns respectively. They both have an ideal core, no leakage inductance, and no resistance. Z1 is supposed to be 30 with a phase angle of 30, which I entered has 25.981 resistance and 15 net reactance. Z2 is supposed to be 60 with a phase angle of -60, which I put has 30 resistance and -51.962 net reactance. Net reactance is the input that Multisim requires for impendence blocks to control the imaginary portion of the impendence. The frequency of voltage source, and inductors are set to 60 Hz. The current entering node where the simulated circuit splits into parallel transformers is 4.03110 A and -22.87476 phase angle. The current going through the inductor in transformer 3 is 499.99657 mA and 60.00023 phase angle.

Also, some thing that I just found out while trying to fix this. This magnitude of 2 for the current going through the primary inductor of T2 only appears in AC Analysis. When I attempt to graph the current with an oscillator, it shows a peak of 4.

To combine another post I made into this one to provide info about the situation. If I were to design the circuit above without the parallel component, the result of the simulations would be in accordance to my handwritten calculations (4 A and phase angle -30). However, the introduction of T3 into the circuit, whether connected or not, halves the current going through T2 in the AC Analysis.

[image: Partial Circuit]
[image: Full Circuit]
T3 somehow affects T2 even if not connected to anything in the simulated circuit.
[image: Floating T3]

Comment: Good Lord. Are screenshots not possible with your OS? At any rate, you're better off using an `.AC` analysis for these kind of measurements.

Comment: Apologizes for quality of the pictures. They were originally intended to be posted on WhatsApp so I quickly took a picture of them. I will be adding higher quality ones shortly.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen What do you mean .AC analysis. For the results in the black box are acquired by Single Frequency AC Analysis. Is there a different type of AC Analysis?

Comment: What value did you enter for AC magnitude of V1? What voltages does it report between points 1-0, 3-4, 5-0? How much current does it report flowing into Z1? What are the parameters of Z1, T1, and T2?

Comment: @BruceAbbott The AC magnitude is 1440 V. Between points 1-0, it reported 1.44k V, 3-4 it reported 480V, 5-0, it reported 240V. The current flowing into Z1 is 7.99999 A with -29.99977 phase angle. T1 and T2 have 3:1 and 2:1 turns respectively. They both have an ideal core, no leakage inductance, and no resistance. Z1 is supposed to be 30 with a phase angle of 30, which I entered has 25.981 resistance and 15 net resistance. Z2 is supposed to be 60 with a phase angle of -60, which I put has 30 resistance and 51.962 net resistance. The frequency of voltage source, and inductors are set to 60 Hz.

Comment: @BruceAbbott The current entering node where the simulated circuit splits into parallel transformers is 4.03110 A and -22.87476 phase angle. The current going through the inductor in transformer 3 is 499.99657 mA and 60.00023 phase angle.

Comment: @JohnSmith Now that you have screenshots, it looks like you did perform an `.AC` analysis (which is possible at a single frequency, too). However, if by "net resistance" you mean reactance then you got the sign wrong in the second impedance. You are also not showing *your* calculations, how do you know those are correct? At any rate, for me LTspice shows 4/-60 for the inductor current, which is not exactly as you claim.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I apologize for not clarifying. By net reactance, I meant the value that one can change in the impedance block in Multisim which is the block that says Z= A + Bj and Z = A - Bj. The reason that I said Z2 has a positive 51.962 imaginary component is because Multisim does not allow negative numbers in the net reactance box which is why the positive value is put into the impendance box where the imaginary component is negative (Z = A - Bj). I commented the information as if it had to be inputted into Multisim rather than the actual inputs.

Comment: The hand calculations that I performed were dividing the voltage in T2 by the impendence in that portion of the circuit. This resulted in the value 8 A with a phase angle of -30. Since the transformers are in a step-down configuration, the current must be 0.5x what it is before the transformer. That's where I arrived at the answer 4 A with a phase angle of -30. This diagrees with the simulated circuit results above.

Comment: Also, some thing that I just found out while trying to fix this. This magnitude of 2 for the current going through the primary inductor of T2 only appears in AC Analysis. When I attempt to graph the current with an oscillator, it shows a peak of 4.

Comment: To combine another post I made into this one to provide info about the situation. If I were to design the circuit above without the parallel component, the result of the simulations would be in accordance to my handwritten calculations (4 A and phase angle -30). However, the introduction of T3 into the circuit, whether connected or not, halves the current going through T2 in the AC Analysis.

Comment: @John All the information in the comments that has the potential to help people answering needs to go in the OP, not stay in the comments. Also, instead of using 100 words to describe what you did, use MathJax to write formulas. It's safe to say that people here know how to read them. It will help you take [the tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand how this site works. For ex.: you're asking why X=Y and not Z, so clearly state X, Y, and Z; you say you tried A, B, and C methods, then show (preferred) or describe A, B, and C. In short: facts, not a mystery novel.

Comment: All your numbers are correct. You have 8 A at the secondary of T2. With a 2:1 ratio it _must_ have 4 A on the primary. Yet the single frequency analysis says 2 A. I feel there is something you aren't telling us. Please do single frequency AC analysis with T3 disconnected and current probes on both sides of T2, and show us the results.

Comment: @BruceAbbott I have added the images to the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the issue. Multisim does not give a message when SPICE cannot solve inductors in parallel with no resistance. In order to solve the circuit above, you need to add a miniscule amount of internal resistance to the inductors which are in parallel (the primary inductor of T2 and T3). Doing so will provide the answer 4 A with a phase angle of -30.

Answer (score 1):

All this time I was looking at the simulation but, it looks like you got the calculation wrong: at the very last step, after correctly calculating the current for \$Z_2\$, you divide that current by 2. Why? The impedance is of the type \$A+jB\$, which means series but, even if it were parallel, you can't just divide it by 2, you have to calculate the current based on the respective resistance/reactance.

So, the current has to be \$8\angle{-30}\$ and this is how to reach it:

$$\begin{align}
Z_2&=30\angle{30}=5\cdot 3^{1.5}+j15 \tag{1} \\
&\Rightarrow \quad
\begin{cases}
R=25.98\;\Omega\\
L=\dfrac{15}{2\pi 60}=39.79\;\text{mH}
\end{cases} \tag{2}
\end{align}$$

You can use the site's CircuitLab but, be sure to use 10 H for the inductances of the transformers (and maybe 0.001 as resistance). Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to perform an `.AC` analysis on one point, only. It opens up a graph which seems to be a minimum of one decade. So I used LTspice (the circuits within the rectangles are ideal transformers, so called "DC trafo"):

[image: SPICE confirmation]

So, at this point, I don't know what you did with Multisim and how the blocks are set (or built, internally) but, I think it's safe to say you simply hammered the thing until it came out as you *thought* it should be. Which is not a very scientific approach. ;-)

Comment: The way that I found the answer was by downloading LTSpice after comments that the results were not matching my Multisim results on that software. When I built my circuit identically, LTSpice gave an notification saying to put some series resistance when inductors are in parallel. I did so and the LTSpice transient simulation ran and gave results that matched my handwritten calculations. Since both LTSpice and Multisim are based on SPICE, I went into the blocks and added an internal resistance of 1n ohm in Multisim. This gave results that matched LTSpice and my handwritten calculations.

Comment: According to the person who answered this post [link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/247624/2-ideal-inductors-in-parallel), SPICE is known to have issues resolving ideal inductors in parallel. LTSpice is aware and prompts a message to its user, Multisim does not.

Comment: @JohnSmith That doesn't change the fact that you got the calculation wrong: it should be 8/-30, not 4/-30. Why did you divide by two in your last equation? That's where the wrong appears. Then you went on to hammer your simulation so that it gives you the result you thought to be right. And if you got the error about paralleled inductors then you could have only got it if you used parallel RL, not *series*, which is what you need. Please read my answer in full, don't skip, there's more than one point I'm addressing.

Comment: I do not understand. The voltage times the current has to be equivalent from both sides of the transformer. Since the transformer is step down, the right side should have 0.5x the voltage and 2x the current which is why comparatively I2 is 0.5x of IZ2. I am new to this so I am not entirely sure, but thats I recalled being teached. Also, the error occurred because of T2 and T3. Are the primary inductors of those two transformers not connected in parallel?

Comment: @JohnSmith Since you've correctly deduced the voltage across \$Z_2\$ then all that's left is to calculate the current through it, which is \$V/Z_2=240/(30\angle{30})=8\angle{-30}\$. I didn't label the nodes in my picture but, if you look at the results, `V(n003)=240` is the voltage across `L1`, which is set as a *series* -- again, ***series*** -- RL. I'm stressing this part because, if you had set it in Multisim as a *series* RL you would not have had problems with paralleling inductors.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you are saying. The voltage across Z2 or in your diagram L1 is 240. The current through Z2 is IZ2 which I calculated to be 8 A, which is the same as yours. The issue I was having is the current through the primary inductor of T2 which the question labels I2. Comparatively, I2 is half of what IZ2 because T2 is a step-down transformer. Thats why I halved IZ2 to find I2. Also, I see what you mean about the inductors being in series. The impendance block in Multisim internally utilizes a resister and inductor/capacitor in series. So that was not the issue.

Comment: At one point while trying to find the issue, I did substitute the impendance block with their component counterpart (inductor and capacitor); however, it did not fix the current I2. I should have probably mentioned that in the original post.

Comment: @JohnSmith Oh, I see now, I thought `I2` is the same as `IZ2`. In that case, LTspice agrees (see `I(F2)`). I'm still a bit foggy as to what Multisim has there and what you did but, since you got the correct results, confetti. BTW, you can accept your own answers (the green check mark). It also helps people in the future, searching for similar questions. If they will see an accepted answer then they will know that is the solution.